# Making a zip code choropleth map using R and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, maps

I am trying to create a choropleth map for zip codes in R using plotly and running into a few issues. I find a lot of documentation on making choropleth maps for county level data, but not much on zip codes.

I have a data frame that looks like this (not the complete df, there are 60 zip codes in total).

```
Zip_list Fail    Pass    Pass/w Conditions
60625   0.278   0.482   0.240   
60640   0.288   0.492   0.220   
60618   0.247   0.501   0.251   
60657   0.281   0.503   0.216   
60639   0.283   0.449   0.268   
60609   0.321   0.481   0.198   
60647   0.229   0.563   0.209   
60620   0.350   0.415   0.235   
60614   0.215   0.500   0.285   
60616   0.261   0.515   0.224
```

I have a geojson file that I downloaded from the Chicago data portal which has the zip code boundaries.
https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-ZIP-Codes/gdcf-axmw

I have been trying to follow along with the examples on their documentation pages.

https://plotly.com/r/mapbox-county-choropleth/

Here is what I have tried:

- `chi_zips` is the geojson file
- `abcd` is my data frame

```r
fig <- plot_ly() 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
    type="choroplethmapbox",
    geojson=chi_zips,
    locations=as.character(abcd$zip_list),
    z=abcd$Fail,
    colorscale="Viridis",
    featureidkey="objectid",
    zmin=0,
    zmax=1,
    marker=list(line=list(
      width=0),
      opacity=0.5
    )
  )
fig <- fig %>% layout(
    mapbox=list(
      style="carto-positron",
      zoom =2,
      center=list(lon= -95.71, lat=37.09))
  )
fig
```

The map renders but it is blank. Not sure where to go from here. From what I understand I have to match the zip codes my data frame to the locations on the geojson file which is what I thought `locations=as.character(abcd$zip_list)` was doing.